# In Excel VBA Search record using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I searched many blogs but still i couldn't find a solution effectively. 
Please help me.

I have worksheet data like this

```
Recipie Ingredient      No of Grams     Ingredient Cost  
A10     OREGANO          0.25 gr        10  
A10     OSTUR           60.00 gr        11  
A10     SÓSA            65.50 gr        14  
Á10     HAKK            38.00 gr        18
```

I want to update ingredient cost for Recipe if already ingredient exists. 
Else i need to insert a new record.

I can do this by using a simple for loop and check for match Recipe and then search ingredient within that Recipe and update. I tried this and this works fine. 
My problem is when no of rows increase to 10K then search will run for all the 10K rows one by one.

I am looking for solution which allows me to search a record by specifying multiple columns in the search and find that single record directly instead of scanning each and every row.

In Autofilter the filter is happening in background and  when macro runs i am able to see 
that filter is happening . I want worksheet to display all the records .

Please help me .

Data Structure is given as below .

Comment: Just as a sidenote: This is a typical example where using Access would allow you to obtain the fastest query results in the most easy way with the least VBA code needed and with the least problems of making modifications later on.

Comment: where are you getting your ingredient cost? Will different recipes have different costs for the same ingredient?

Answer (score 0):

As I put in my comment above, this is a typical functionality you should Access for (even when you prefer to use Excel as a front). What I see above is a table structure, food asked to be queried before being fed to the spreadsheet.

MS Access allows you to create indexes and searches based on index, which has the purpose to considerably increase your performance when you have many records. (The system will search based on the indexed records, rather than needing to run through every single record). If you are talking about a table with 10K records, I suspect Access is without a doubt better to go with.

Although I don't recommend it, you can treat your Excel sheet as a database table using ADODB or DAO (Access uses native DAO) by adding a library reference to the file. 
This way you can use SQL to perform all CRUD operations on your datasheet.
The reason why I don't recommend it, is because Excel is not meant to be replaced by a RDBMS (eg does not support relational db structures, which makes it harder to support and which makes that you need to manage your referential/data integrity through VBA or manually.
Learning how to do a few basic things in Access may take you 1 day, but maintaining this system by programming everything (including checks and retrieving data from another sheet-table etc...) may take you forever.

Additionally:
The reason why the code will be slow is because I suspect that you read and check every record explicitly line per line from the Excel sheet.
If you still want to have this code run faster using loops, you need to read the entire range into an array and perform the checks in memory by looping through the array.
I suspect the code execution to be acceptable but you can check its performance by setting a timer, and an additional notification of the progress on the statusbar (application.statusbar) displaying the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a lot of luck using the `Find` method instead of looping but these days I find myself using the `Dictionary` object more and more, especially for tasks like these. You need to have "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" enabled as a reference from the Tools menu, then it's simple like:

```
Dim dCompare As New Dictionary 
....
For i = 2 To bottomRow
    dCompare.Add (Worksheets("...").Range("L" & i).value & Worksheets("...").Range("I" & i).value), i
Next i
```

Basically you can fill it how you want, but I just concatenate the worksheet values that I need as the keys and put the row number as the value. Then for the retrieval:

```
Function findCorrelate(ByVal value1, value2 As String) As Long
Dim oppositeRow As Long
    oppositeRow = dCompare.Item(value1 & value2)
findCorrelate = oppositeRow
End Function
```

You put in the values that you need searching for (which together is the key) and it will spit out the row number for you if it exists, as the value. else it will return 0 (but you might like it better as -1). This way you only need to loop once. At the very least, you'll see a significant decrease in execution time doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make some recommendation:
1. declare dCompare as Dictionary at module level
2. create a new instance of dCompare in the procedure where you fill in the dictionary:

```
Set dCompare = New Dictionary
```

3.convert as string all values making up the KEY  `CStr(Value1)`,...

1. discard all objects when they are not useful anymore (the quotes do not work???):

   If Not dCompare Is Nothing Then Set dCompare = Nothing

5.Declare your arguments the right way:

```
findCorrelate(ByVal value1 As String, ByVal value2 As String) As Long
```

and not:

I like to use this very powerful object too

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something simple as a vlookup to find the price (per unit) for the ingredient in another worksheet (or another range on the same worksheet)?

It would mean for a price update or ingredient addition you need to chang/add something at one location only. Which could then even be done manually, instead of by means of VBA.